# Account Ledger display query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

There are 2 tables Ledger and transaction

Ledger Table has below fields

LID,LName,Lgroup,Opbal

Transaction Table has
Txno,Tandate,LID,TXnType,Amount,Narration

Below Are The data

Ledger Table

```
LID, LName,  Lgroup,  Opbal
1    Salary   Expense 10000
2    Cash     Asset   20000
3    Electricty Expense -1000
```

Transaction Table has

```
Txno,   Tandate,  LID,Amount
1    2022-01-01    2     -10000              
1    2022-01-01    1      2000
1    2022-01-01    3      8000
```

Required Ledger Display

If Cash Ledger is selected

```
Txno Txndate       Lanme      Debit Credit Balance 
1    2022-01-01     Salary    2000         18000 
1   2022-01-01     Electricty 8000         10000
```

If Salary Ledger is selected

```
Txno Txndate       Lanme      Debit Credit Balance
1    2022-01-01     cash             2000  12000
```

If Electricity Ledger is selected

```
Txno Txndate       Lanme      Debit Credit balance
1    2022-01-01     cash             8000   7000
```

Have tried the below SQL but it does not work - for example if I query Salary ledger the all the ledger including Salary ledger is displayed, rather than the expected result I showed above.

```sql
SELECT T1.TxnNo,
       T1.Txndate,
       t2.LName,
       ISNULL(T1.Debit, 0) AS Dr,
       ISNULL(T1.Credit, 0) AS Cr
FROM [Transaction] T1
     INNER JOIN (SELECT LID,
                        LName
                 FROM Ledger
                 WHERE LID IN (SELECT Ledger.LID FROM Ledger)) t2 ON T1.Lid = t2.LID
                 INNER JOIN (SELECT TxnNo, Lid FROM [Transaction] ) t3 ON t3.TxnNo = T1.TxnNo AND t2.LID = t3.Lid where t2.LID=1;
```

db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=e221e2b2a9a999b11efc8ca63b8ecfb6)

The Logic is when a Ledger is selected the Other ledger posted against that ledger should be displayed as per the Voucher entry. IF as per the voucher entry if cash transaction is done cash voucher is passed debiting the expense like salary and electricity. So when we query on cash ledger the result should display Electricity and Salary and if salary OR electricity ledger is queried then Cash Ledger Should be displayed with amount of Salary Or Amount electricity as per the query

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246233/discussion-on-question-by-wave-account-ledger-display-query).